# Pass Param Javascript to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Trying to send a variable called "sitename" to Node.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(sitename);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/images",
        data: sitename,
        dataType: "json"
    })
        .done(function (json) {
            alert(json);
        });
});
```

`console.log(sitename)` gives me wanted `results = dagan`

Now on Node.js I have this code:

```
app.post('/images', function (req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    var sitename= console.log(req.param.body);
    var BucketName = 'webwedding/'sitename;
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {Bucket: BucketName, Key: '*',ResponseContentType : 'application/json'};
    s3.getObject(params).
        on('httpData', function(chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.write('<html><body><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,')
            res.write(new Buffer(chunk).toString('base64'));
            res.end('"/><</body></html>');
        }).
        on('httpDone', function() { }).
        send();
});
```

Well `console.log (req.body) gives me -> **{ dagan: '' }**` and not `dagan`.

The other one is undefined.

2.Small Question-> Am I able to list a bucket/folder and get all object inside? if so any directions will be good, thanks Ahead!

**SOLVED!**
adeneo, it's the correct answer "Use data: {sitename : sitename}, and req.param.sitename" ,thanks

Just for the others that might have some issues with this, Client-Side: `data: {"sitename": sitename}`. Server-Side: `var sitename = req.param('sitename');`
to be more specific :)

Comment: Use `data: {sitename : sitename}`, and `req.param.sitename`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to stringify the data with:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ sitename: sitename }),
```

on the node site have you something like

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```